# Calling malloc() overwrites static table

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, stm32

I'm working on ARM Cortex M4F (M3) inside STM32F4 microcontroller, without OS. Language is pure C.

I'm having a problem with malloc() function. The code below uses global and volatile table of data read from SD card (volatile unsigned char[] fat_sector_buffer). Within the function I'm declaring pointer memory (struct type used to read data from table as struct), and allocating memory as a second struct holding date and time from RTC.

The problem is, that when I use malloc(), memory is allocated on fat_sector_buffer.

Code:

```
unsigned char fat16_update_entry()
{
uint8_t looking=1;
unsigned int i=0;
char ret=0;
Fat16Entry *data;   
DateTimeStruct *dt=malloc(sizeof(DateTimeStruct));
unsigned short time,date;
dt= read_calendar(dt); //Read calendar date and time
    ...
```

What I get after malloc is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv0Mn.png

Why is it happening and how do I solve it?

Comment: Could you show us how and where fat_sector_buffer is allocated, and the relationship between the code you posted and the allocation? If malloc /really/ is allocating from the heap across a global (without you doing anything), libc has a serious issue. If this is what's happening I'd suggest something else is corrupting the heap so and breaking malloc(). Can you run valgrind on your platform?

Comment: Hello,
as for Valgrind, it is impossible due to fact that this is no-os (embedded) application. fat_sector_buffer is unsigned char array, which size is 512. This is not a problem of indexing out of table (index of the error place is 224). I've checked memory configuration, and ranges not covering.

Comment: is the `fat_sector_buffer` variable a memory-mapped variable, and therefore declared with a fixed address? if so: is this address _really_ likely to change? or can you do away with the `volatile` all together (without optimization issues that may bring about, of course)

Comment: It is unlikely to change. In fact, earlier it didn't have volatile identifier because it is not required here, it was added just to see whether it helps (it didn't).

Comment: Please, learn to format code, this look really bad!

Comment: @meaning-matters I looks bad here, because SO formated it this way, in IDE it is formated. Also what formating would You expect in declarations? There are no nested ifs or anything.

Comment: What toolchain are you using? Your debugger might support setting a breakpoint on memory write - that way you can find out exactly where the memory is being overwritten.  Also, when using a runtime library on a no-OS platform, there's usually some configuration that *you* need to do to provide heap memory and initialize the heap. You might want to explain how that's being done.

Comment: I'm using keil uV4 with default set of tools, with default set of settings provided for this unit. Currently I'm at home so I cannot check exact values but it might me it. However according to this http://www.keil.com/forum/11132/ and this http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_qSBQYnN3-MU/TIRYnvWql1I/AAAAAAAAADQ/5KvCo9EZ7KU/s320/proccontext.jpg Cortex M4 has SRAM configuration which does not allow heap to enter variables sector, and when heap is full it makes malloc return NULL. What obviously is not happening here.

Comment: Come on, don't you notice the lack of indentation inside the block starting with { ???

Comment: @Axel Do you use the standard startup assembly file? How much big is the  heap_size is defined there?

Comment: Yes,I do. Project is preety advanced so ammount of ram for heap has been set to 5k.

Answer (score 0):

The post doesn't indicate how the memory fat_sector_buffer points to was actually allocated, how big it is, or how it was filled.  So hard to say if it actually getting written over.

malloc does not actually write anything to the memory it allocates.  Just reserves it and provides a pointer.

Comment: fat_sector_buffer is global variable 
volatile unsigned char fat_write_sector_buf[FAT_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE];
where FAT_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE is equal to 512. So it is not issue of reading/writting to indexes of table.

Comment: Post indicates it is an char array.  How big?

Comment: (I accidentally pressed enter, it is 512 as written above)

Comment: @PudDog Welcome on SO. You answer may have been questions in comments. Post real answers to get reputation.

Comment: is it possible that the malloc arena is not initialized or is pointing to the memory where the program is loaded?  I assume malloc is not returning NULL?

Comment: @is it possible that the malloc arena is not initialized - no, because I use it later, and the data are valid. Also, it NULLifies the memory region to be allocated so it works

Comment: @program mem - impossible due to architecture. It is modified harvard so program memory and data are separate. Also, code works well except for this one place.

Comment: @return NULL, no it returns pointer to beginning of allocated structure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers to your questions above (you've ensured `fat_sector_write_buf` is statically allocated and sufficiently large), I am guessing you have a corrupted heap. Something is saying to the heap manager that there is available memory to allocate which falls within `fat_sector_write_buf`, and that's why `malloc()` is returning it. I would guess something is overwriting a pointer on the heap. It's a pity you can't use `valgrind` as this would find it very quickly.

Therefore you will need to debug whatever is overwriting the heap. Your libc may offer some heap/malloc debugging, for instance:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Allocation-Debugging.html#Allocation-Debugging
though this will be dependent on your libc build. You can (by inspecting source for libc) determine how the heap is MEANT to work, and call something to check (immediately prior to the malloc), that the bogus block is in fact on the heap. You may also be able to use remote debugging to step through `malloc()` and find out why it is returning the bogus value. Obviously this will be dependent on your platform.

As another possibility, you might simply have a memory leak and have run out of memory. Normally the stack grows down and the heap grows up, so the first thing an oversized stack or heap hits is the other one. However, on an embedded platform, it might well hit static data.

Comment: As for the leak, I assumed it at the beginning but tests have shown that it is nearly impossible. Due to nature of this project malloc is used fairly rarely (20 times in code) so I've tracked if all "malloc's" have their "free's" and they do. I'd give You useful but my reputation is too low. Sorry.

Comment: Re malloc, note that other things will allocate memory via the heap allocator, e.g. `strdup`. I suspect if you can't use shared c library malloc debugging, you might want to use your own malloc with debugging wrapping the existing one.